# Multi select checkbox ajax table filter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hello previously i'm working on Multiple select checkbox to display the table record can be found at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749349/multiple-select-checkbox-to-display-the-table-record/40750206#40750206) . Now i try to change the previous one by using ajax method and removing the submit button and it will be filter the table when value is selected without submit button. my problem here is passing the multiple value using ajax.

**index.php**

```
            <script>
        function getCOMPANY(val) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data:'companyname='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#company-list").html(data);
            }
            });
        }
        </script>

        <form name="frmSearch" id="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
            <label>Client Name&nbsp;</label>
            <select id="multiple-checkboxes" multiple="multiple" class="companyInput" onChange="getCOMPANY(this.value);" name="COMPANYNAME[]">   
            <?php
                $query = mysqli_query($conn_connection, "SELECT * FROM sl_iv GROUP by COMPANYNAME");

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["COMPANYNAME"]."'".($row["COMPANYNAME"]==$_POST["COMPANYNAME"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["COMPANYNAME"]."</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </form>

        <div name="state" id="company-list" class="companyInput">
            <table>
                <center>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="3%" style="text-align:center"><span></span></th>
                        <th width="20%" style="text-align:center"><span>Customer Name</span></th>
                        <th width="10%" style="text-align:center"><span>Terms</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                </center>

                <tbody>
                <?php

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                        $docno=$row['DOCNO']; 
                        $cmpName=$row['COMPANYNAME'];

                        $m++;

                    ?>                
                    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo<?php echo $m?>" class="accordion-toggle">
                        <td><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" type="button"><span class=""></span></button></td>
                        <td><input type="text" style="text-align:center; font-size:15px" class="form-control input-sm CompanyName" id="CompanyName0" name="CompanyName" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['COMPANYNAME']);?>" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="text" style="text-align:center; font-size:15px" class="form-control input-sm terms" id="terms0" name="terms" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['terms']);?>" readonly></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                            <td colspan="10">
                                <div id="demo<?php echo $m?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr style="background-color:#A9DC60; color:black;">

                                    </tr>
                                    <?php 
                                        $sql_1="SELECT * FROM `ar_iv` Inner Join `sl_iv` On ar_iv.DOCNO = sl_iv.DOCNO  Inner Join `payment_terms` On ar_iv.TERMS = payment_terms.id WHERE sl_iv.`COMPANYNAME`='".$cmpName."' ";
                                        $query_1 = mysqli_query($conn_connection, $sql_1);

                                        while($DetRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_1)) {
                                    ?>
                                    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo<?php echo $m?>" class="accordion-toggle">
                                        <td width="3%"><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" type="button"><span class=""></span></button></td>
                                        <td width="27%" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $DetRow['DOCNO'] ?></td>
                                        <td width="10%" style="text-align:center"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($child['DOCAMT']); ?></td>    
                                    </tr>

                                    <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                    </tr>

                <?php
                }
                }else {
                echo "0 results";
                }
                ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#multiple-checkboxes').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
            });
        </script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
            <?php
        session_start();
        require_once('../include/mysqlconnection.php');
        $m=0;//div collapse
            $query = "SELECT * From `sl_iv` Inner Join `ar_iv` On ar_iv.DOCNO = sl_iv.DOCNO Inner Join `payment_terms` On ar_iv.TERMS = payment_terms.id GROUP BY COMPANYNAME";
            $results = mysqli_query($conn_connection,$query);
        ?>

        <body class="reports" onload="calculateSum()">

            <table>
                <center>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="3%" style="text-align:center"><span></span></th>
                        <th width="20%" style="text-align:center"><span>Customer Name</span></th>
                        <th width="10%" style="text-align:center"><span>Terms</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                </center>
        <?php
            if(!empty($_POST['companyname'])) {

            $COMPANYNAME = $_POST['companyname'];
            $COMPANYNAME = is_array($COMPANYNAME) ? $COMPANYNAME : [$COMPANYNAME];
            $companiesParam = '\''. join("', '", $COMPANYNAME) . '\'';
            $fetch = "SELECT * FROM `sl_iv` Inner Join `ar_iv` On ar_iv.DOCNO = sl_iv.DOCNO Inner Join `payment_terms` On ar_iv.TERMS = payment_terms.id WHERE COMPANYNAME IN (".$companiesParam.") GROUP BY COMPANYNAME";
            $results = mysqli_query($conn_connection,$fetch)or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn_connection) . "<hr>\nQuery: $fetch");

            }
            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                $docno=$row['DOCNO']; 
                $cmpName=$row['COMPANYNAME'];

                $m++;
        ?>
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo<?php echo $m?>" class="accordion-toggle">
                <td><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" type="button"><span class=""></span></button></td>
                <td><input type="text" style="text-align:center; font-size:15px" class="form-control input-sm CompanyName" id="CompanyName0" name="CompanyName" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['COMPANYNAME']);?>" readonly></td>
                <td><input type="text" style="text-align:center; font-size:15px" class="form-control input-sm terms" id="terms0" name="terms" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['terms']);?>" readonly></td>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="10">
                    <div id="demo<?php echo $m?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <table  class="table">
                        <tr style="background-color:#A9DC60; color:black;">

                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                        $sql_1="SELECT * FROM `ar_iv` Inner Join `sl_iv` On ar_iv.DOCNO = sl_iv.DOCNO  Inner Join `payment_terms` On ar_iv.TERMS = payment_terms.id WHERE sl_iv.`COMPANYNAME`='".$cmpName."' ";
                        $query_1 = mysqli_query($conn_connection, $sql_1);

                        while($DetRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_1)) 
                        ?>

                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo<?php echo $m?>" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td width="3%"><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" type="button"><span class=""></span></button></td>
                            <td width="27%" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $DetRow['DOCNO'] ?></td>
                            <td width="10%" style="text-align:center"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($child['DOCAMT']); ?></td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                            }
                            ?>
            </table>
                    </div>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        }else {
             echo "0 results";
            }
        ?>
        </table>
```

**report.php**

```
            <?php
        require_once('../include/mysqlconnection.php');
        include("../include/mpdf/mpdf.php");
        $m=0;

        $COMPANYNAME = $_GET["COMPANYNAME"];
        $terms = $_GET['terms'];

        $item_q = "SELECT * From `sl_iv`";
        if($COMPANYNAME!=""){

            $item_q.= " WHERE COMPANYNAME = '".$COMPANYNAME."'";
        }
        if($terms != "")
        {
            $item_q.= " WHERE terms = '".$terms."'";
        }
        else{
            $item_q.= " GROUP BY COMPANYNAME ";
        }

        $item = mysqli_query($conn_connection, $item_q);
        //$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,47,47,10,10); 

        $mpdf = new mPDF(
            '',    // mode - default ''
            'A4',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
            '',     // font size - default 0

        $stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdf.css');
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);

        $header = '
        <table>

        </table>
        ';

        $footer = '
        ';

        $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
        $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);

        $html = '
        <style>
        .gradient {
            background-color: #F0FFFF;
        }
        </style>

        <p align="center" style="font color: #191970; font-size:20px"><b>Customer</b></p>


        <table width="100%" class="no-spacing" style=" vertical-align: middle; font color: #191970; font-family: serif; font-size: 9pt;">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color:#F0FFFF;">
                    <th><span>Company Name</span></th>
                    <th><span>Terms</span></th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);    
            if (mysqli_num_rows($item) > 0) {

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item)) {
            $m++;

        $html = '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['COMPANYNAME'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['terms'].'</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="7">
                        <div id="demo'.$m.'" class="accordian-body collapse">
                            <table  class="no-spacing">
                                <tr>
                                </tr>
                ';

        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

                            $sql_1="SELECT * FROM `ar_iv` Inner Join `sl_iv` On ar_iv.DOCNO = sl_iv.DOCNO WHERE sl_iv.COMPANYNAME ='".$row['COMPANYNAME']."'";
                            $query_1 = mysqli_query($conn_connection, $sql_1);

                            while($DetRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_1)) {
        $html = '
                                    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo'.$m.'" class="accordion-toggle">
                                        <td>'.$DetRow['DOCNO'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$DetRow['DOCAMT'].'</td>
                                    </tr>';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                            }

        $html = '
                </table>

                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <br>';



        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }                                                               
        $html = '
            </tbody>
        </table>';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

        $filename = $search.".pdf";
        $mpdf->Output($filename,I);

        exit;
        ?>
```

Comment: I don't get why you would ever do this...!? If you're making an ajax request...get JSON and use it to populate your client side template using Underscore templates or something. Sending back a bunch of HTML to stuff into a div with jQuery is a total mess!

Comment: from what i said previous i didnt use any ajax for my code and now im trying to use ajax method so it will be a mess. for me it working fine and im trying to use ajax.   corrrect me if im mistakely use the ajax for me code

Comment: If you need to send the contents of a form, you will want to serialize your form when you send your ajax:  `data: $('#frmSearch').serialize()`. This will send all the values of the form.

Comment: Also, I don't really see a problem sending back html, but you scripting is very procedural which is inherently messy looking and inefficient. I think if you clean up your script with functions and or class/methods, it would help your set-up a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my latest update. it working but not sure whether its correct or not.

**index.php**

```
            <script>
        function getCOMPANY() {
            var form = document.frmSearch;
            var dataString = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_aging.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){
                $("#company-list").html(data);
            }
            });
            return false;
        }
        </script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST)) {
        $COMPANYNAME = ($_POST);

        $COMPANYNAME = $_POST['COMPANYNAME'];
        $COMPANYNAME = is_array($COMPANYNAME) ? $COMPANYNAME : [$COMPANYNAME];

        $companiesParam = '\''. join("', '", $COMPANYNAME) . '\'';
        $fetch = "SELECT * FROM `sl_iv` Inner Join `ar_iv` On ar_iv.DOCNO = sl_iv.DOCNO Inner Join `payment_terms` On ar_iv.TERMS = payment_terms.id WHERE COMPANYNAME IN (".$companiesParam.") GROUP BY COMPANYNAME";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn_connection,$fetch)or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn_connection) . "<hr>\nQuery: $fetch");

        }
```

then i have another problem at **ajax.php** for the display report button. it said /reports/report.php?COMPANYNAME=Array&terms=

```
            <a href="report.php?COMPANYNAME=<?php echo $companiesParam; ?>&terms=<?php echo $terms; ?>" target="_blank">
            <button style="margin-right:16px; float: right;" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> PRINT Detail
            </button>
        </a>
```

**report.php**

```
            <?php
        require_once('../include/mysqlconnection.php');
        include("../include/mpdf/mpdf.php");
        $m=0;

        $COMPANYNAME = $_GET["COMPANYNAME"];
        $terms = $_GET['terms'];

        $item_q = "SELECT * From `sl_iv`";
        if($COMPANYNAME!=""){

            $item_q.= " WHERE COMPANYNAME = '".$COMPANYNAME."'";
        }
        if($terms != "")
        {
            $item_q.= " WHERE terms = '".$terms."'";
        }
        else{
            $item_q.= " GROUP BY COMPANYNAME ";
        }

        $item = mysqli_query($conn_connection, $item_q);
        //$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,47,47,10,10); 

        $mpdf = new mPDF(
            '',    // mode - default ''
            'A4',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
            '',     // font size - default 0

        $stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdf.css');
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);

        $header = '
        <table>

        </table>
        ';

        $footer = '
        ';

        $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
        $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);

        $html = '
        <style>
        .gradient {
            background-color: #F0FFFF;
        }
        </style>

        <p align="center" style="font color: #191970; font-size:20px"><b>Customer</b></p>


        <table width="100%" class="no-spacing" style=" vertical-align: middle; font color: #191970; font-family: serif; font-size: 9pt;">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color:#F0FFFF;">
                    <th><span>Company Name</span></th>
                    <th><span>Terms</span></th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);    
            if (mysqli_num_rows($item) > 0) {

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item)) {
            $m++;

        $html = '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['COMPANYNAME'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['terms'].'</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="7">
                        <div id="demo'.$m.'" class="accordian-body collapse">
                            <table  class="no-spacing">
                                <tr>
                                </tr>
                ';

        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

                            $sql_1="SELECT * FROM `ar_iv` Inner Join `sl_iv` On ar_iv.DOCNO = sl_iv.DOCNO WHERE sl_iv.COMPANYNAME ='".$row['COMPANYNAME']."'";
                            $query_1 = mysqli_query($conn_connection, $sql_1);

                            while($DetRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_1)) {
        $html = '
                                    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo'.$m.'" class="accordion-toggle">
                                        <td>'.$DetRow['DOCNO'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$DetRow['DOCAMT'].'</td>
                                    </tr>';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                            }

        $html = '
                </table>

                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <br>';



        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }                                                               
        $html = '
            </tbody>
        </table>';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

        $filename = $search.".pdf";
        $mpdf->Output($filename,I);

        exit;
        ?>
```

Comment: Edit your question with the update, don't post an answer. You are getting `Array` now because it's an array from your form (from serializing), not just one value. You have to choose from the array what you want to use.

Comment: okSORRY. NOW i able to pass the array by change the echo $COMPANYNAME to echo $companiesParam at my link button... so at my report.php should i use $COMPANYNAME = $GET['COMANYNAME']  to get the array value? i read about unserialize how to use it?

Comment: Serializing is basically turning the form into a long query string. Since you are using post for the Ajax, you have to use post to get values from the form data

Comment: so i just update my code above which im include the report.php.. i cannot fetch the value that passed via url parameter to the report.php by using $_GET

Comment: No you need to use $_POST

Comment: i tried change it to $_POST and it show all the record.. not the selected value record..

Comment: Give me a bit of time to demonstrate some things to try.

Comment: ok sure . i still not yet solve the passing array to my report

Comment: Where are you even referencing that report page? I don't see it anywhere being refrenced?

Comment: at the button  *<a href="report.php?COMPANYNAME=<?php echo $companiesParam; ?>&terms=<?php echo $terms; ?>" target="_blank">
            <button style="margin-right:16px; float: right;" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> PRINT Detail
            </button>
        </a>* and get the value that passed via button

Comment: Oh I see it there. Your scripting is a bit convoluted, it's hard to follow because you don't take advantage of functions/class/methods. Honestly, most of this I would do differently but for that link you need to `print_r($companiesParam);` to determine what of the array you want to keep.

Comment: for my ajax.php `<a href="report.php?COMPANYNAME=<?php echo $companiesParam; ?>&terms=<?php echo $terms; ?>" target="_blank">` ok tried by creating new report,php to print out the selected value `<?php
require_once('../include/mysqlconnection.php');
include("../include/mpdf/mpdf.php");

$COMPANYNAME = $_GET['COMPANYNAME'];
echo print_r($COMPANYNAME);
?>` and it showing 'Cauã Dias Alves', 'James S. Almendarez'1 .. << that is my selected value.. problem only occur when i insert the  condition IF for the query. it didnt fetch all the array value

Comment: Yeah, you have to modify your `if` statement to accommodate the multiple values

Comment: You should edit this post with the right answer then mark it correct.